# Is the set $\{ (x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:x^3+y^3=1 \}$ compact or not?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Problem:** Is the set $\{ (x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:x^3+y^3=1 \}$ compact or not?
>
> **Solution:** $\{(x,y):x^3+y^3=1 \}$ is compact if it is closed and bounded

But I don't know "how to check it".

Comment: This question is a hit. I saw that a few times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The set is not bounded: Take $x$ large negative, and let $y=\sqrt[3]{1-x^3}$.

**Remark:** The set *is* closed.

Comment: But answer is $\{ (x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:x^3+y^3=1 \}$ is compact

Comment: The answer will be "compact" if we **change** $\mathbb{R}^2$ to, for example, $\mathbb{R}_+^2$, the pairs of non-negative reals.  But not, if, as the problem currently specifies, $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: If X is taken as a large negative, Y accordingly will be a large positive number and I don't exactly see how that's a problem.@aAndre Nicolas

Comment: It means there are points in the set arbitrarily far from the origin. Tht means the set is unbounded. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, no unbounded set is compact.

Answer (score 0):

I think this set is unbounded as if we take $x=999^{-1/3}$ and $y=1000^{1/3}$ which satisfies the equation but if we increase these values in the same way then it will become unbouned

Comment: Please use Mathjax